# Recovering time function from its single-sided spectrum + its Hermitian

Tags: matlab, fft, spectrum, ifft

I am trying to get  a real wavelet, `w`, which is a column vector, from its single-sided Discrete Fourier Transform.  According to the theory,  the negative frequency side is complex-conjugate of the positive frequency side, but in implementing it in Matlab (using the `ifft` function) is giving me a headache.

Below,  I am listing   a small program that transforms a damped sine wavelet, `w`,  into frequency domain as `W`, then extracting the positive part and augmenting it with `conj(flipud(W))`, but the inverse FFT of it  looks like my input wavelet amplitude modulated with something else . However, `w = ifft(W,'symmetric')` works fine. Any suggestions to identify the problem will be highly appreciated.

Here is the listing:

```
clc; clear all
% Genetate a damped sine wavelet
n = 100;
n2 = floor(n/2)+ 1;
dt = .25;
for i  = 1:n
    t = (i-1)*dt;
    w(i,1) = 100 * sin(t) * exp(-0.2*t);
end

figure; subplot(3,2,1);  plot(w);
title('The Signal')
%-------------------------------------
W1  = fft(w);                 % 2-sided
n2 = floor(n/2)+ 1;
W2  = fft(w,n2);              % 1-sided
subplot(3,2,3);plot(real(W2));
title('2-sided abs(W2)')
subplot(3,2,5);plot(imag(W2));
title('2-sided angle(W2)')
%-------------------------------------

w1 = ifft( W1 ) ;                 % Works fine
subplot(3,2,2); plot( w1);
title( ' w2 = ifft(W2);   (2-sided) ' );

% --------------------------------------
% Use the /symmetric/ option of ifft() with
% the single-sided spectrum

w2 = ifft(W2 , 'symmetric');  % 1-sided, works fine

subplot(3,2,4);plot(w2,'k');
title( 'w2 = ifft(W2, "symmetric" )')

% --------------------------------------
% Calculate the complex-cojugate of 1-sided W2
% (excluding the zero frequency point?!), flip it,
% and attach it to the tail of W2 col vector.

H  = flipud(conj(W2(2:n2)));
W3  = [W2 ; H];
w3 = ifft( W3 ) ;    % sourse of my migraine headache
% If you let n =1000 instead of the 100, the effect of
% amplitude-modulation-like effect is less and the output
% (bottom right graph)resembles the input wavelet but
% with a thicker line.
% If n=100 and W2(1:n2-1) in H = ... is used instead
% of the W2(2:n2), you'll get a flying bold eagle!


subplot(3,2,6);plot(w3,'k');
title('w3 = ifft([W2 ; H]')
%---end of the program-------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this line:

```
W2  = fft(w,n2);              % 1-sided
```

Unlike the implied assumption that this would return the first `n2` outputs of the full `length(w)`-sized FFT (if that were the case it would give you the expected 1-sided spectrum), this line instead returns the full FFT (2-sided spectrum) of the sequence `w` truncated to `n2` samples.

The fix is then to compute a full FFT of `W` and then pick the first `n2` samples of the result, as your updated code does with:

```
W1 = fft(w);
W2 = W1(1:n2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works but I haven't yet figured out why the previous one didn't:

```
clc; clear all

% Genetate a damped sine wavelet
n = 101;  n2 = floor(n/2) + 1; dt = 0.25;

t = [(0:1:n-1)*dt]'; w = sin(t).*exp(-0.2*t);

figure; subplot(2,1,1);plot(w); 
title('The Wavelet')

W1   = fft(w);                % 2-sided
W2  = W1(1:n2);               % 1-sided

H  = flipud ( conj( W1(2:n2) ) );
W3 = [W2 ; H];  
w3 = ifft(W3);                % 2-sided

subplot(2,1,2); plot(w3); 
title('w3 = ifft( [ W3; H ]')

%---------- end of the program----------
```

Answer (score 0):

Down is an augmented version of your sample code at the very begining. The fundamental issue is about the ifft at the end. Consider scaling the real part with (pi./df).

Your 'augmented code' as follows:

```
close all; clear all; clc; 

% Genetate a damped sine wavelet
n = 512;  n2 = floor(n/2) + 1; dt = 0.25; 
fs=1/dt;   % Digitised data should ever have a sampling rate -right! 

f=linspace(0,fs,n); % Your frequency axis 
df=mean(diff(f)); % Your incrementation on the frequency axis
fc=f(12); % Just to get a monochromatic data in time, frequency is needed    
          % f(12) just to obey the sampling constraints not more than f(n/2+1)


t = [(0:1:n-1)*dt]; w = cos(2.*pi.*fc.*t).*exp(-0.2*t);

figure; subplot(2,1,1);plot(t,w); 
title('The Wavelet')

W1   = fft(w)./n;                % 2-sided
W2  = W1(1:n2);               % 1-sided

H  = fliplr (conj(W1(2:n2-1))); % Intended to stick with the data length...
W3 = [W2 , H];  
w3 = (pi./df).*real(ifft(W3));                % 2-sided (see the scaling)

subplot(2,1,2); plot(w3); 
title('w3 = ifft( [ W3; H ]')

fprintf('Data size at the beginning:\n');
size(w)
fprintf('Final sata size:\n');
size(w3)
```